# How to parse and list all class methods using nikic/PHP-Parser

Tags: php, lexer

Reading the docs I can dump the collected information but there are no examples of iterating over the collection to filter by a particular node type.

```
use PhpParser\ParserFactory;
use PhpParser\Error;
$parser = (new ParserFactory)->create(ParserFactory::PREFER_PHP7);
try {
    $statements = $parser->parse(file_get_contents("SomeClass.php"));
    $methods = array_filter($statements, function($statement) {
        // some form of filtering for methods
    });
} catch (Error $exception) {
    echo "parse error ~> ", $exception->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: There should be visitor classes if I remember correctly

Comment: See also: https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser/blob/master/doc/2_Usage_of_basic_components.markdown#node-traversation with Node\Stmt\ClassMethod

Comment: Have you solved this? Do you still need it?

Answer (score 2):

## Option 1 - Simple node finding

```php
use PhpParser\{Node, NodeFinder, ParserFactory};

/** Parse file. */
$parser = (new ParserFactory)->create(ParserFactory::PREFER_PHP7);
$stmts  = $parser->parse(file_get_contents("SomeClass.php"));

/** Traverse. */
$nodeFinder = new NodeFinder();
$methods = $nodeFinder->findInstanceOf($stmts, Node\Stmt\ClassMethod::class);

/** Dump. */
var_dump($methods);
```

## Option 2 - Full "Node Visitor" mechanism

```php
use PhpParser\{Node, NodeTraverser, NodeVisitorAbstract, ParserFactory};

/** Filter definition. */
$methods   = [];
$traverser = new NodeTraverser();
$traverser->addVisitor(new class extends NodeVisitorAbstract {
    function enterNode(Node $node) {
        if ($node instanceof Node\Stmt\ClassMethod) {
            global $methods;
            $methods[] = $node;
            return NodeTraverser::DONT_TRAVERSE_CHILDREN;
        }
    }
});

/** Parse file. */
$parser = (new ParserFactory)->create(ParserFactory::PREFER_PHP7);
$stmts  = $parser->parse(file_get_contents("SomeClass.php"));

/** Traverse using our filter. */
$traverser->traverse($stmts);

/** Dump. */
var_dump( $methods );
```

Comment: These are very helpful code example, thank you. Can you add an explanation of when you would choose each option? As they look to give the same results in this situation

Comment: To @PeterB and anyone wandering about that: In this case the only difference is use of `NodeTraverser::DONT_TRAVERSE_CHILDREN`, with this you can skip searching for nodes in impossible locations. For example if you don't care about anonymous classes you will not see named class inside an another class, thus whole class node could be skipped. Under the hood `NodeFinder` also uses `NodeTraverser`. [(documentation)](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser/blob/master/doc/2_Usage_of_basic_components.markdown#node-traversation)